# Repeated vertices in cycles (graph theory)

Tags: graphs

In graph theory, can a cycle contain repeated nodes/vertices not including the first and last ones? If so, can you please give an example?

Comment: I suggest referring to the formal definition that I previously provided to you: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_%28graph_theory%29, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_%28graph_theory%29#Circuit_and_cycle.  What does it say?  Or, you could consult a textbook and see what definition it provides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually cycles are assumed not to have any repeating vertices (other than the first and last vertices being identical). If repeating vertices are allowed, then one talks about *closed walks*. In order to stress that cycles have no repeating vertices, we call them *simple cycles*.

That said, terminology isn't always fixed. If in doubt, define the terms you use.

Answer (score 1):

A cycle does not contain repeated vertices (and does not have a starting vertex).

In contrast, a *closed walk* starts at a vertex, has a sequence of vertices and edges (with repetitions allowed), and ends at the starting point.  A *closed trail* starts at a vertex, has a sequence of vertices and edges (with edges distinct, but vertices may be repeated), and ends at the starting point.  A *cycle* is a closed walk (of length at least 3) that does not repeat vertices and that has no starting vertex and no direction.

These are standard definitions; see [Bollobas, “Modern Graph Theory”, GTM 184, p. 4-5].